# php foreach - group by then do something after the 'group' changes

Tags: php, foreach

Consider this data:

```
make            model       color
----            -----       -----
Volskwagen      Golf        Red
Volskwagen      Golf        Green
Volskwagen      Golf        Blue
Toyota          Corolla     Red
Toyota          Corolla     Green
Toyota          Corolla     Blue
Toyota          Corolla     Black
```

The below code will run through this data and effectively group the vehicle make and models:

```
$sql = "SELECT make, model, color FROM t_cars ORDER BY make, model;";
$rows = $db->query($sql);

$group = '';
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($group != $row['make'].$row['model']) {
        echo $row['color'] . '<br />';
        $group = $row['make'].$row['model'];
    }
}
```

The output will be simply:

```
red
red
```

What I want to be able to do is output (within the `foreach` somewhere is:

```
'There are 3 Volkswagen Golfs. The colors are Red, Green, Blue' 
'There are 4 Toyota Corollas. The colors are Red, Green, Blue, Black'
```

My actual code is much more complex than this, but if I get this logic right, I should be ok. The only constraint is that I need all this in the one containing `foreach` statement like in the demo.

Comment: It will require a second foreach, but why not save the values in an associative array using the makes as a key referencing another associative array with the model as the key referencing an array containing the possible colors.

I'd type out an example but I'm on a phone.

What's the reasoning behind the one foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using mysql and willing to change your sql query, you can use this query to help you out.

SELECT make, model, group_concat(color separator ',') AS colors, count(color) as colorcount FROM database
  GROUP BY make, model

Okay.

This will leave you with a query that would return:

[Volskwagen] [Golf] [Red,Green,Blue] [3]

[Toyota] [Corolla] [Red,Green,Blue,Black] [4]

Then you can do if colorcount > 1 add s to "Golf."
You can do a replace on the commas to ad a space after each comma.
You can do a replace on the last comma in colors with " and".